# combinatorics/graph theory question on a deck of mn cards

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

i'm review graph theory, there's one problem that i think i've seen it in combinatorics. how can these two problems be solved using in different views? can someone help me?

if we have a deck of mn cards with m face values and n suites, we put the cards randomly into n*m matrix, why there is a set of m cards, one in each column, having distinct values?

thanks!

Comment: Have you learnt the Hall marriage theorem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** [Hall marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Let the men be represented by the $m$ face values, and the women be represented by the columns. Draw a line from the women to the man if the man lies in the women. Check that the marriage conditions holds, and so we can marry them off.

---

(I am not condoning pre-marital sex.)